# Obtaining the federated identity provider's access token via AWS Cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, access-token, federated-identity

I'm trying to obtain the access token provided by my federated identity provider (Azure AD) that I've setup in AWS Cognito. My idea is to obtain it post-authentication so a Lambda function can obtain further details of the user through Graph API, using the access token.

My initial idea was to make use of the 'aws-amplify' library but it seems that is not possible due to the size of the resulting node_modules folder (I tried to create a layer with it, so I could reference the library but the files exceed the allowed constrain),

What other way do you recommend? Is my approach correct? Any ideas are welcome!